# codeigniter - subquery limit not showing

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, subquery, limit

I have this:

`$this->db->select('(select var_value from contents where table = "products" and table_id = products.id and var_name = "image" and name = "images" order by id asc limit 1) as main_picture');`

`$this->db->where('category_id', $cat)->from('products')->limit($limit, $start)->get();`

The problem is that codeigniter is removing the "limit 1" inside the subquery...

Any advice?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `LIMIT` inside `$this->db->select();` method
Please refer to Active Record [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)

- `$this->db->get();`
- `$this->db->get_where();`

Are the only methods that allow the use of `LIMIT`

Comment: so, i cannot put a limit 1 inside the subquery?